# how to get only one column names in linq using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
    var ColName = "";
    var model = new AttributeMappingSource().GetModel(typeof(DataClassesDataContext));
    foreach (var mt in model.GetTables())
    {
        if (mt.TableName == "dbo.Sheet")
        {
            foreach (var dm in mt.RowType.DataMembers)
            {
                ColName = dm.MappedName + ", ";
                Response.Write(ColName);
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my code to get column name but I need only one column name.

Thank You

Comment: Which of them do you want? The first, last, any?

Comment: any, like 3 column name or 4th

Comment: I need only one column name from the table, like in my table there is 4 column name[Id, Name, Mobile, Salary] so I want only "Name" column. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: but what is the result type you are expecting? You know the name of the column, right?

Comment: yes, I know the column name, but this code gives me the list of column name but I want only one column name.

Comment: And which column name do you want? Use a random number generator and pick one at random? A particular one (e.g. always #3)? The first one (e.g. `Id`)?

Comment: Try `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: hey, I have an idea, the getting the list of column name from the table right this column exactly do this but if this column name can we add into List<> and then get particular one of the column name from it.

Comment: can anyone help me on this point.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the name of the column you want you can condense this all down into a couple of linq statements (or one if you can guarantee that the table exists. I'd recommend the first suggestion as it's slightly safer, this still assumes that the column you want exists in the data set and so will throw if it does not exist. You can change the `.First()` call to use `.FirstOrDefault()` and then check `ColumnName` for null for extra safety.

## Safe LINQ statements

```
string ColumnName;
var columnYouWant = "the column you want";
var model = new AttributeMappingSource().GetModel(typeof(DataClassesDataContext));
var table = model.GetTables().FirstOrDefault(table => table.TableName == "dbo.Sheet");
if(table != null)
    ColumnName = table.RowType.DataMembers
    .First(member => member.MappedName == columnYouWant);
```

## Unsafe (must guarantee that dbo.Sheet table exists)

```
var columnYouWant = "the column you want";
string ColumnName = new AttributeMappingSource()
    .GetModel(typeof(DataClassesDataContext))
    .GetTables()
    .First(table => table.TableName == "dbo.Sheet")
        .RowType.DataMembers
            .First(member => member.MappedName == columnYouWant);
```